# Check multiple variables for null and define them accordingly

Tags: c#, if-statement, variables, null

I have a way here how I check multiple variables for null, and fill them with the correct data according to the nullness. However, this way is very messy and I am now wondering if there is a better way to do this.

`

```
try
{
    user = new ADUser();

    nextEntry = ldapSearch.Next();

    var attName = nextEntry.getAttribute("name");
    var attMail = nextEntry.getAttribute("mail");
    var attTelephone = nextEntry.getAttribute("telephoneNumber");


    if(attName == null || attMail == null || attTelephone == null)
    {
        if( attName == null) 
        {
            user.name = ""; 
        }
        else 
        { 
            user.name = attName.StringValue; 
        }
        if(attMail == null)
        {
            user.mail = "";
        }
        else
        {
            user.mail = attMail.StringValue;
        }
        if(attTelephone == null)
        {
            user.telephone = "";
        }
        else
        {
            user.telephone = attTelephone.StringValue;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        user.name = attName.StringValue;
        user.mail = attMail.StringValue;
        user.telephone = attTelephone.StringValue;
    }

                        

    model.ADUserList.Add(user);
}
catch
{
    continue;
}
```

`

I have tried it my way, but I think it can be done cleaner.

Comment: I think you can take advantage of the `nullable` operator and `nullish-coalescing operator`: `user.name = attName?.StringValue ?? ""; user.mail = attMail?.StringValue ?? ""; user.telephone = attTelephone?.StringValue ?? "";`

Comment: Can `attName.StringValue` be null? (If it can then `user.name = attName?.StringValue ?? "";` would have a different result than the original code)

Comment: @nbokmans NOW THIS IS CLEAN!! Thank You, it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can achive the same result without any 'if-else':

```
user.name = attName?.StringValue ?? "";
user.mail = attMail?.StringValue ?? "";
user.telephone = attTelephone?.StringValue ?? "";
```

you can also write an extension method to return the empty string:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string EmptyIfNull(this string str)
    {
        return str ?? String.Empty;
    }
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
user.name = attName?.StringValue.EmptyIfNull();
user.mail = attMail?.StringValue.EmptyIfNull();
user.telephone = attTelephone?.StringValue.EmptyIfNull();
```